# Query get rows that don't contain any item collection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM MYTABLE
```

and that will return:

```
ABCD123DEF
XASD123ERD
XASD456ERD
XASD456ERD
RETR789GHF
```

Now what I need is to run a query where I get all items from `MYTABLE` that don't contain `123` or `456`

So I need to return only this item because the rest of them either contain 123 or 456.

```
RETR789GHF
```

PS. The list will be dynamic so I cannot hard code it `not like '%123%' or not like '%456%'`

Comment: I think we'll need a little more context on what you are trying to do here.   You say the list will be dynamic?  Care to explain more what you mean?    What do you mean by list?  Are you wanting to pass multiple values into a stored procedure and then filter based on those multiple values?  Is this list stored in another table somewhere?

Comment: Great where does this dynamic list come from?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `not like`:

```
where value not like '%123%' and
      value not like '%456%'
```

Comment: i just added an edit to my question. Sorry for miss information, the list will be dynamic so I cannot hard code it

Comment: @user2818430 . . . This question is clearly about two specific values.  If you have another question, then ask as a *new* question with a clear description of your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you “cannot hardcore it“, does that men that there can be any numeric digits? As yet we can only guess, so maybe this helps:

```
where value not like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```